# Facing issues while trying to receive Real Time Updates from Facebook

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a `Mvc-facebook` Application. I have configured my **Facebook-Sample app** in the Facebook Site.

**Purpose of Sample Facebook App**
Whenever I make some change in the first Name. Facebook should send the changes to my Web-Server in the form of JSon.

I have successfully configured the Subscription.

[image]

Facebook sent the token. Matched it with my code and my code sent the same token to Facebook. It's very good so far.

**Issues 1** - In my Web-Server, I have Fiddler installed. When Facebook sends token to my Web-Server IIS, Fiddler is not showing the request.

**Issue 2** - when I made some changes in my First Name, Facebook is not sending the data to my Web Server.

Please tell me what is missing in these issues.

**Code**

```
[HttpGet]
[FacebookSubscriptionVerify("MyToken")]
public void Verify(FacebookClient fb)
{
    Response.Write(fb.AccessToken);
    var verifiedResult = new FacebookSubscriptionVerifiedResult();
    verifiedResult.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext);
}

[HttpPost]
[FacebookSubscriptionReceived]
[ActionName("Verify")]
public void ReceiveUserUpdates(object subscription)
{
}
```

Comment: Fiddler acts like a proxy. Did you setup fiddler to accept all web requests and relay them to IIS? By default it does nothing unless somebody subscribes to the proxy. Even better is just to look at the IIS logs, or if you would see more in-depth information you could use tools like Wireshark.

Answer (score 0):

> In my Web-Server, I have Fiddler installed. When Facebook sends token to my Web-Server IIS, Fiddler is not showing the request.

Well, that does not sound as if your debugging/monitoring was successful, does it? You say before, that Facebook has actually sent you the token.

Find other means of debugging, f.e. have a look into the server’s access log.

> when I made some changes in my First Name, Facebook is not sending the data to my Web Server.

If you deduce that the same way as you did above, then you probably deduced wrong …?

---

Be aware, that the POST requests Facebook sends for Realtime Updates are not in the “normal” format you would expect from f.e. an HTML form post, that means not as `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Comment: You said **Find other means of debugging, f.e. have a look into the server’s access log.** How to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Use wireshark to check what is sent, that will give you a correct view. Just capture everything and check http protocol.